# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando popular uma datatable, mas não estou consegundo de jeito nenhum. Poderiam me ajudar?

============= Avaliativo_Relatorio - Model ========

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Avaliativo_Relatorio extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'email',
        'courseid',
        'fullname'
    ];
}
```

============= Avaliativo_RelatorioController - Controller ========

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Avaliativo_Relatorio;

use Yajra\DataTables\Facades\DataTables;

class Avaliativo_RelatorioController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('relatorios_ava.avaliativo_relatorio');
    }

    public function get_datatable_avaliativo()
    {
        $avaliativo = Avaliativo_Relatorio::table('mdl_role_assignments')
        ->join('mdl_context', 'mdl_role_assignments.contextid', '=', 'mdl_context.id')
        ->join('mdl_course', 'mdl_course.id', '=', 'mdl_context.instanceid')
        ->join('mdl_user', 'mdl_user.id', '=', 'mdl_role_assignments.userid')
        ->where('mdl_context.contextlevel','=',50)
        ->where('mdl_role_assignments.roleid','=',5);
        return Datatables::of($avaliativo)->make(true);
    }
}
```

============= avaliativo_relatorio.blade ========

ID
                      Nome
                      Sobrenome
                      E-mail
                      Id Curso
                      Curso

============= master.blade ========

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#users-table-avaliativo').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Exibindo _MENU_ registros por página",
            "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado - desculpe",
            "info": "Exibindo página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ total registros)",
            "sLoadingRecords":  "Carregando Registros...",
            "sProcessing":      "Processando...",
            "sSearch":          "Pesquisar",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":       "Primeira",
            "sPrevious":    "Anterior",
            "sNext":        "Próxima",
            "sLast":        "Última"
        }
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('relatorios_ava.avaliativo_relatorio.get_datatable_avaliativo') }}",
        "columns":[
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "firstname"},
            {"data": "lastname"},
            {"data": "email"},
            {"data": "courseid"},
            {"data": "fullname"}
        ]
     });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de `Avaliativo_Relatorio`, use:

```
$avaliativo = \DB::table('mdl_role_assignments')...->get();
```

Ou você pode adicionar a propriedade `$table` a classe `Avaliativo_Relatorio`, assim:

```
protected $table = 'mdl_role_assignments';
```

E depois fazer usar aquele mesmo código sem a função `table`, assim:

```
Avaliativo_Relatorio::join('mdl_context', 'mdl_role_assignments.contextid', '=', 'mdl_context.id')...->get();
```

Dessa forma, você conseguirá fazer a chamada no banco de dados presumindo que não haja mais nenhum erro.

Comment: eu coloquei ->get() no final da get_datatable_avaliativo, é sumiu o erro de "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()". O problema agora é que agora ele esta exibindo a página mas quando eu a atualizo aparece o erro no datatable.  "DataTables warning: table id=users-table-avaliativo - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7". Eu não sei porque ele esta buscando esta tabela users-table-avaliativo, pois estou especificando que a minha conexão é a mysql2 na minha model que é uma outra base de dados externa que uso.

Comment: Esse problema não é de conexão, é no html, o JavaScript está tentando buscar um elemento com o `id` igual a `users-table-avaliativo` mas não está achando, verifique se a sua `table` está assim `<table id="users-table-avaliativo"...`

Comment: Sim, está correíssimo, $('#users-table-avaliativo').DataTable({  que chama a  <table id="users-table-avaliativo" class="table">

Comment: Eu não sei, não esta populando de jeito nenhum. Poderiam me ajudar, pode ser que minha consulta com eloquent esteja errada. Como eu faria para passar o seguinte query abaixo para ELOQUENT?

SELECT u.id, u.firstname,u.lastname,u.email,c.id 
AS courseid,c.fullname 
FROM mdl_role_assignments rs 
INNER JOIN mdl_context e ON rs.contextid=e.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = e.instanceid 
INNER JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id=rs.userid 
WHERE e.contextlevel=50 
AND rs.roleid=5

Comment: Coloque aquela query no Eloquent da sua pergunta na função `dd(query);` e veja se houve algum retorno. Se não, você usa uma [`query` pura sem `Eloquent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22925451/how-can-i-query-raw-via-eloquent) através do `\DB::select(queryPura);` e joga o resultado no `dd` para ver se buscou algo.